# recompile NGINX with upgraded openssl

Tags: nginx, openssl

I am trying to recompile my NGINX with upgraded version of openssl using below command.

```
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module
```

on runnng make I am gettng following error.

> Makefile is older than Makefile.org, Configure or config. Reconfigure
>   the source tree (via './config' or 'perl Configure'), please. make[2]:
>   *** [Makefile] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/openssl' make[1]: ***
>   [/usr/local/src/openssl/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 2

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove Makefile from openssl folder.

```
rm /usr/local/src/openssl/Makefile
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Nginx should just do this for us on every install!

Answer (score 0):

For me this error came after i changed my system's timezone to invalid timezone by mistake.
Please "Check your system clock